# Given 4 mutually non-intersecting lines in the given projective spaces of dimension $3$, how many lines intersect them all?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following question as a part of my homework set, I'm having trouble deciding on how to approach the problem:

Given 4 mutually non-intersecting lines in **a)** $\mathbb{P(C^4)} \ $ **b)** $\mathbb{P(R^4)}$ how many lines intersect them all?

I know that in $\mathbb{P_3}$, 3 mutually non-intersecting line have infinite many lines intersecting them, forming the ruling unique smooth quadric. What can I say if I introduce a 4th line? So, is it correct to say that there are at most 2 lines intersecting them? As the 4th line will intersect the quadric at at most 2 points?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^{3})$?

Comment: No, I mean $\mathbb{P(C^4)}$

Comment: Sorry. I was confused. $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^{4})=\mathbb{P}^{3}_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Here is an argument due to Schubert : we can perturb these line and the number can be the same, so we perturb them so that $L_1$ intersects only $L_2$ in $P$ and $L_3$ intersects only $L_4$ in $Q$. 
Now clearly $\overline{PQ}$ intersects the four lines. If $L'$ is another line passing not by $P$ or $Q$ it should be contained in the plane spanned by $L_1,L_2$ and the plane spanned by $L_3,L_4$, that is this line is uniquely determined, so there is only two such lines.

Comment: I'm not sure what perturb means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know part a). I'm not sure about part b).

If the 4th line also lie on the smooth quadric, then the lines all have the same ruling, so there will be infinitely many lines intersecting all 4 lines. If the 4th line intersect the smooth quadric in one or two points, then there will be one or two lines intersecting all 4 lines.

You can also look at the book undergraduate algebraic geometry by Miles Reid, section 7.5.

Comment: Wouldn't this argument be possible for b) as well?

Comment: I'm not sure. The class I'm taking assume $k$ is algebraically closed. So I don't know whether the result that three disjoint lines are contained in a unique smooth quadric is still true over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah! I see, that's true

Comment: Regarding the real case, see: Hilbert, David; Cohn-Vossen, Stephan (1952), Geometry and the Imagination (2nd ed.), Chelsea, p. 15.: "Thus three skew straight lines always define a hyperboloid of one sheet, except in the case where they are all parallel to one plane (but not to each other). In this case they define a new type of second-order surface called the hyperbolic paraboloid, which does not include any surface of revolution as a special case."

Comment: If the underlying field isn't closed, we include the possibility that the 4th line may not intersect the quadric at all, called an exterior line. That should solve it.